# subsetting by rows and columns

Tags: r, subset

When I do the following simple code:

```
myMatrix <- matrix(1:15, nrow=3)
rownames(myMatrix) <- c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(myMatrix) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
myMatrix1 = myMatrix[A, c("A", "B")]
```

I get the following error message:

> ```
> Error in myMatrix[A, c("A", "B")] : subscript out of bounds
> ```

What's wrong with the code? I want to subset the matrix by particular row and column that obviously do exist in that matrix...

Comment: For convenience, the object LETTERS is available. Try `LETTERS[1:3]` in your console.

Comment: Thanks! That helps (though is not provided in examples for subsetting for some reason). But now the names of rows are deleted from the new matrix. Is that possible to keep them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is based on the row name index which should be quoted

```
myMatrix ["A", c("A", "B"), drop = FALSE]
```

Otherwise, it thinks that 'A' is an object which store some row names

Comment: Thanks! That helps (though is not provided in examples for subsetting for some reason). But now the names of rows are deleted from the new matrix. Is that possible to keep them?

Comment: @AlexM  We need to add `drop = FALSE` to avoid the matrix getting converted to `vector` when there is only a single row